# Do footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have such code (all)
http://jsfiddle.net/NSzdm/

But main trouble is that i try to do as usual footer at the bottom of the page, but i get something like this:
[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/59666091/screen001.jpg]

Simple there is still wrapper with center, but also i have footer, which must be after wrapper... Please see jsfiddle, all code is there...

footer css:

```
.footer {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #3b3b3b 0%, #424242 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #3b3b3b 0%, #424242 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #3b3b3b 0%, #424242 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #3b3b3b 0%, #424242 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff3b3b3b', endColorstr='#ff424242',GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  width: 100%;
  height: 144px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to change position:absolute to position:relative in your CSS for .wrapper .center {position:relative}.

That seemed to move your footer down, not sure if it affects the other parts of your page, hard to tell with no images.

Comment: when i set relative my center has magic height... it is much smaller then must be... also seem's to be that footer is positioning via that center div which height is not understandable

Comment: Sorry, I also realized I added  <div style="clear:both;"></div> above your footer.

Using your fiddle in Chrome, change position:relative and add  <div style="clear:both;"></div> above footer DIV.

Comment: this also maybe is via that wrapper is very small by height... but must be tall